# Getting an info from the DB with Tables and Updating it

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

Hi guys im having a difficulty with this scenario:

I want to get the product information using modals, i got this following code:

```
    //Model.php
    public function getProduct($product_id){
    $this->db->select('product_id,product_name,product_price,product_qty');
    $this->db->from('tbl_products');
    $this->db->where('product_id',$product_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
    }

    //Controller.php
    public function view_product(){
    $product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->data["post"] = $this->Model->ProductList();
    $this->load->view('product_page',$this->data);
    $this->data["post"] = $this->Model->getProduct($product_id);
    $this->load->view('modal/update_product',$this->data);
    }

    //update_product.php (modal) my View
    lets just go straight into the form
    <form action="" method="post">
    <?php foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "product_id" value = "<?php echo $post->product_id;?>"/>
    <input type = "text" name = "product_name" value = "<?php echo $post->product_name;?>"/>
    <input type = "text" name = "product_price" value = "<?php echo $post->product_price;?>"/>
    <input type = "text" name = "product_qty" value = "<?php echo $post->product_qty;?>"/>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
    <?php } ?>
    </form>
```

I got a table already: i can see all products, in my product_page.php
Here is the tables face looks like:

```
    ID        Name        Price        Quantity        Option
    1        Shoes        150.00        1                Update
    2        Liquor        67.50        5                Update
    3        Paint        1000.00       5                Update
```

Once I click the Update button, the update_product.php(a modal) will pop up and get the result of 1 of the product, if I press the first Update only the information for Shoes will be inside the modal, at first i tried it, I get all the information of all the products which makes my modal redundant and looping due to foreach, then I tried getting the information from the table ID itself, and no product pops out, how can I see only 1 product using modal? thank you very much maam and sirs. Please I really need youre help :(

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not really clear what you're asking, Here is an answer to you question. Your controller code doesn't seem to be making any sense.If you want to display all your products in on page and then you want to edit/update a product when clicked on corresponding update link, here is what you can do.

**Use single controller method for list and update**

```
//Controller.php
public function view_product(){
    $product_id = (isset($this->input->post('product_id')) ? $this->input->post('product_id'): False ;
    if($product_id == False){
        $this->data["post"] = $this->Model->ProductList();
        $this->load->view('product_page',$this->data);
    } else{
        $this->data["post"] = $this->Model->getProduct($product_id);
        $this->load->view('modal/update_product',$this->data);
    }
}
```

This is simple modification to your code to make it work correctly, but since this code cannot handle form submission of the update form (unless you're pointing update form to a different controller), you will have to add some other code to this controller and your code will get messy in no time. My personal suggestion to you is this,

**Use different controllers for list view and update**

```
//Controller.php

public function view_product(){
    $this->data["post"] = $this->Model->ProductList();
    $this->load->view('product_page',$this->data);
}

public function update_product($product_id){
    if($this->input>post('submit')){   // 'submit'should be replaced with the name attribute of your submit button
        //call your model and handle the update form submission here
    }
    $this->data["post"] = $this->Model->getProduct($product_id);
    $this->load->view('product_page',$this->data);
 }
```

now, update option of your product_page.php should point to 'update_product' controller method with corresponding product id *e.g. {base_url}/controller_class_name/update_product/1*

I think your product_page.php has some code like this to loop through all the products and display products in a table, now when you click update link it will point to update_product controller and it will handle the update process.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Option</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if(!$products){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">No result</td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($products){ ?>
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $product->id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->price; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->quantity; ?></td>
                <td>                        
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller_class_name/update_product/<?php echo $product->id; ?>" >Update</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You won't be needing a foreach loop inside your update_product.php because you're updating only one product at once.

Hope this is the answer you're looking for, if not please comment and I will edit the answer accordingly.